# Jquery Mobile adds random divs to my SELECT

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, ripple

This is my problem:

I got this code in my GUI editor:

```
<select>
    <option>Pick a number</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that, when I run it in my ripple emulator, it turn to be this...

```
<div class="ui-select">
    <div id="select-11-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <span>Pick a number</span>
    <select>
        <option>Pick a number</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

I dont know how to prevent that to happens.

Any help?

Thx!

Comment: Add `data-role="none"` to select.

Comment: @vohuman undefined undercover? ;)

Comment: @Omar Maybe in future ;)